# Submitting data via POST to sql and then printing that

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forum

I am trying to make a basic forum/board where anyone can simply post a message via a submit for.  So far I've been able to send the text they've entered via POST and put it into a MySql table.  I am wondering how I then can go and print on the webpage what was just submitted?

Answer (score -1):

Well if it's on the same page / script as the MySQL insertion, then you can take it from post, however I suggest using htmlspecialchars() to remove any HTML that people could embed in to their data.

If it's not on the same page, as it won't always be, then use MySQL to retrieve the data with a `SELECT` query - See here for help: [W3Schools - SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) - and, again, use htmlspecialchars() on it and display it in your desired format.

This is a very vague question for StackOverflow, so I can't really give you much more information unless you give me something that you've already tried, something I can correct / alter.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've used a SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y = ? $_POST("Z") statement and I've attempted to just print_r($_POST).  What I'm trying to get at is this: I have placed some text into MySql, and now I want to post said text underneath the original post and <textarea> people type in, I just don't understand how to post comments basically.  How does a comment go from my typing here to being posted onto StackOverflow? How do I do that (I'm not looking to get into Ajax right now, PHP will do)

Comment: You'll have to get the information with PHP on the actual posts page itself and echo it from the results array that is returned from the MySQL query. If you're not sure how to achieve that, you're best off looking at some PHP / MySQL tutorials and learning how it all works first. What happened when you used the SELECT query?